# Odoo - write to field in separate model through one2many relation field

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to write to a field inside a different model that is related through a one2many. When the user associates a System to a Press while viewing the Press form, I want to push data from the Press to the System.

I'm running Odoo 16.0 cloud-hosted. I used @api.onchange() to watch for a change to system_ids and then push data from the Press to the System. system_ids is a one2many field in the Press class, so I am using a for loop to iterate all the system_ids. There are several fields I'd like to push, but for simplicity I'm only showing one in the code below.

I don't get any errors when executing, it just doesn't actually fill in the data. Debugging has confirmed that the program is iterating through each of the system_ids and is reaching the write() statement.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Press(models.Model):
    _name = 'press.press'
    _description = 'Press Model'

    name = fields.Char()
    system_ids = fields.One2many('system.system', 'press_id', string='Systems')
    oem_serial = fields.Char("Press OEM Serial Num.")

    @api.onchange('system_ids')
    def _onchange_system_ids(self):
        if self.system_ids:
            for record in self.system_ids:
                if record.press_oem_serial == False:
                    record.write({'press_oem_serial': self.oem_serial})

class System(models.Model):
    _name = 'system.system'
    _description = 'System Model'

    name = fields.Char()
    press_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='press.press', string="Press")
    press_oem_serial = fields.Char("Press OEM Serial Num.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `onchange` is correct but the `onchange api` used to change the value of the fields exists in the form view so you need to add `press_oem_serial` into the tree view of `system.system` and you can do that in two ways:

**Solution 1:**
Add the field `press_oem_serial` in the tree view of the One2many `system_ids` field in Press Form view as below:

```
        <record id="press_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Press</field>
            <field name="model">press.press</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <sheet>
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h3>
                                <field name="name" placeholder="Enter Press"/>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <group >
                            <group>
                                <field name="oem_serial"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="Systems " name="systems">
                                <field name="system_ids">
                                    <tree>
                                        <field name="name"/>
                                        <field name="press_oem_serial"/>
                                    </tree>
                                </field>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

**Solution 2:**

Add the `press_oem_serial`  to the tree view for `system.system` model and it will be shown automatically when you use `system_ids` field without tree view in press form.

System tree view

```
   <record id="system_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">System Tree View</field>
            <field name="model">system.system</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="press_oem_serial"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Press Form view:

```
<record id="press_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Press Form View</field>
            <field name="model">press.press</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <sheet>
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h3>
                                <field name="name" placeholder="Enter Press"/>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="oem_serial"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="Systems " name="systems">
                                <field name="system_ids"/>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Root cause is correct. Thank you! I had to implement the .xml slightly differently, but once the field is on the form it can updated properly.